# python lxml - selecting xpath without double slash

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

[The documentation about xpath states that if there is no slash in the xpath, the expression will select elements wherever they are](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

However trying so with lxml.html in python doesnt work:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
s = requests.session()
page= s.get('http://lxml.de/')
html = lxml.html.fromstring(page.text)
p=html.xpath('p')
```

here `p` is an empty list.

I need to use instead `p=html.xpath('//p')`.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: w3schools is not "the documentation". It's a tutorial site produced by a third party with no connection to W3C. Some people find it helpful, others don't. In my view it's often quite good as a quick lookup for little details you've forgotten, but it's pretty weak at explaining concepts you never knew in the first place.

Comment: This particular page on w3schools tries to explain path expressions without a single mention of the word "context" or "focus", concepts which are absolutely essential to understand the difference in semantics between absolute path expressions (starting in '/') and relative path expressions (starting typically with an element name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page likely does not being with `<p>` (i.e., the root) but `<html>` which you assume with that xpath expression.

Either use double slash, `//p`, to retrieve all `<p>` elements or walk down with absolute reference to specific `<p>`. Below demonstrates with first paragraph content:

```
p = html.xpath('/html/body/div/p')

print(p[0].text)
# lxml is the most feature-rich
# and easy-to-use library
# for processing XML and HTML
# in the Python language.
```

Equivalently:

```
p = html.xpath('//p')

print(p[0].text)    
# lxml is the most feature-rich
# and easy-to-use library
# for processing XML and HTML
# in the Python language.
```

Parsing `<p>` without forward slashes which requires a previous xpath with search path slashes:

```
div = p = html.xpath('/html/body/div')[0]    
p = div.xpath('p')

print(p[0].text)
# lxml is the most feature-rich
# and easy-to-use library
# for processing XML and HTML
# in the Python language.
```

Comment: Thx for your reply: I knew how to retrieve the target data, it is also mentionned in my question. I just wanted to get rid of the double slash at the start, to have neater expressions. Please have a look at the link to the xpath documenation i provide in the question: It clearly states that without double slashes, the expression will "Selects all nodes with the name "nodename"". It is not mentionned that without slashes the retrieved element are at root. In fact that would be the behavior of the single slash.

Comment: [W3C Schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) is not a reliable site. I have never seen such an XPath expression with just naming a *nodename* and all nodes return. Some type of slash is needed. Possibly that bullet meant within a certain context which does make sense. But to get to that context you need a search path with `/`.